# Allowing end users to modify rules file

Tags: drools

I have a set of rules for each of my user. Right now, these rules are setup in a file. But I want to allow my users to modify / add rules. The rules aren't that complicated. For instance, below are a couple of rules:

```
rule "Rule 1"
    when
        $order : OrderInfo(getOrderDate() < new Date(...)
    then
        $order.setReturnEligibility(false);
end

rule "Rule 2"
when
    $item : ItemInfo( nonReturnableCategory.contains(getItemCategory().toLowerCase()) )
then
    $item.setReturnEligibility(false);
end

rule "Rule 3"
    when
        $item : ItemInfo( isFinalSale())
    then
        $item.setReturnMethod(...);
end
```

I want to build a UI similar to Drools workbench. But this is for the end customer, so I want it to be a very simple, user-friendly UI. And I was planning to store the rules in a database.

I want to allow the users to add new rules and modify existing ones. For instance, if Rule 3 above was not available, the user will have a dropdown in the UI, where they can select the item categories which are not returnable. Or they can enable or disable any of the rules etc.

What I wanted to know is, what is the best way to maintain the rules? Should I just have the entire rules file as a string in DB with some sort of place holders, and modify the string as and when the user adds / updates the rules? I'm using Drools 6.2. I know the question is kind of vague, but I have no idea how / where to begin, so any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your "end users" know at least a solid subset of Java? Are you *sure?*

Answer (score 0):

If modifying an existing rule means that only the constraint changes the "text with place holder" might be a good idea.

However, I would not store the entire DRL file as a DB entry. Probably a system where individual rules are stored as entities would work best. Attributes would be a name, the text, an "is selected" attribute etc.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'm planning to follow your method of storing individual rules as separate entities. However, I have another question regarding the performance, which I've asked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671645/drools-concerns-about-performance-and-thread-safety. Any suggestions for that?